# Remove subfolders with the same name if empty

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Assuming I have a folder called trial that contains the following:
Folder1, Folder2, Folder3,...Folder5
And each of these folders has a subfolder called FF-15

Thus, the path is:
`'/Users/brianadams/school/trial/Folder1/FF-15'`, or `'/Users/brianadams/school/trial/Folder2/FF-15'`, and so on.

I want to delete folder FF-15 if it is empty from all the Folders.

I tried the following:

```
import glob
import os 
path = glob.glob('/Users/brianadams/school/trial/**/FF-15')
os.removedirs(path)
```

But it throws up an error or does not end up deleting the file.

Comment: What error does it throw up?

Comment: _But it throws up an error_ Are we supposed to guess what the error is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate through each file directory for this to work. You can't delete them from all at once. Slightly modified code, this should work for you.

```py
import glob
import os

ff15_dirs = glob.glob('/Users/brianadams/school/trial/**/FF-15', recursive=True)

for ff15_dir in ff15_dirs:
    if not os.listdir(ff15_dir):
        os.rmdir(ff15_dir)
```

Edit: Works, I just tested it with a file directory I created using your constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Further to Caleb Carlson's answer provided above, the following worked for me:

```
import glob
import os
import shutil

ff15_dirs = glob.glob('/Users/brianadams/school/trial/**/FF-15', recursive=True)

for ff15_dir in ff15_dirs:
    shutil.rmtree(ff15_dir)
```